# A Green Border Around My C# WinForm Application

Tags: c#, .net

I created a **minimal WinForm Application in C#**.
Everything Works Fine but for some reason a **"Green border" Surrounds My Application**.

I Pasted the code down below.

***[program.cs]***

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
            // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

***[Form1.cs]***

```
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int counter = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.progressBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
            this.backgroundWorker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
            this.textanimationWorker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 40F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(543, 209);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(466, 72);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "Uploading RootKit.";
            this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(43, 508);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(222, 70);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button1.Text = "Upload RootKit";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // progressBar1
            // 
            this.progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(43, 284);
            this.progressBar1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 1;
            this.progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
            this.progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1";
            this.progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1037, 23);
            this.progressBar1.Step = 1;
            this.progressBar1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.progressBar1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.progressBar1_Click);
            // 
            // backgroundWorker1
            // 
            this.backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            this.backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
            this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
            // 
            // textanimationWorker
            // 
            this.textanimationWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            this.textanimationWorker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.textanimationWorker_DoWork);
            this.textanimationWorker.ProgressChanged += new System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler(this.textanimationWorker_ProgressChanged);
            this.textanimationWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.textanimationWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1036, 594);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(86, 15);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 3;
            this.label2.Text = "DECRAT V1.0.0";
            this.label2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label2_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaptionText;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1134, 618);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.progressBar1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loading Form1.. Please wait..");

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            textanimationWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            

        }

        private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            counter = 50;
            MessageBox.Show("Uploaded RootKit Successfully!");
            counter = 0;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value += 1;
        }

        private void textanimationWorker_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (counter <= 10)
            {
                if (counter <= 3)
                {
                    counter++;
                    textanimationWorker.ReportProgress(0);
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                else if(counter == 50){
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    counter = 0;
                    textanimationWorker.ReportProgress(0);
                }
            }
        }

        private void textanimationWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (counter == 1)
            {
                label1.Text = "Uploading RootKit";
            }
            else { 
                label1.Text += ".";
            }
        }

        private void textanimationWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**FYI:** I also published it to an exe file but still the green border does not disappear!

I Thought the green border appears just when I code so that I know where the border is but the issue seems with C# ? or probably with something else ?

EDIT [Adding More information]: I want the green border to disappear.
Here is a photo of the Application..

[image: GreenBorder Application]

Comment: "I also published it to an exe file but still the green border does not disappear"
Are you expecting a green box or not? The description and post body explain opposite scenarios.

Comment: @BabakNaffas I Edited My Question by adding more information 

Comment: *"Uploading RootKit."* says it all for me..

Comment: The green box means the executable is being sandboxed.

Answer (score 0):

Green box Indicates **The Executable or the program is sandboxed.**
I am using **COMODO Antivirus** and it **sandboxed** it.

By Turning the antivirus off for a min and running the program the green box disappeared **indicating** that the **executable is not sandboxed.**